# How can I get exception code in C#?

Tags: c#

Is there anything like exception code? that i can know that on different languages operation system i can recognize the same exception?

I need to recognize 'Acces to the COMn Port is denied' and then do some action, is that possible? has this exception any specified type?

Comment: What have you tried? Also being a bit more specific as to what you're trying to do would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the sounds of it you will be getting a [`System.UnauthorizedAccessException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.unauthorizedaccessexception.aspx) (this assumption has been made from [Googling](http://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=seb&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&sa=X&ei=VgFOT9jJJ8eW0QWQ0dyeBQ&ved=0CB0QvwUoAQ&q=Access+to+the+COM+Port+is+denied&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=de780500abb25caa&ix=seb&ion=1&biw=1245&bih=765) the error message and finding [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/tfssetup/thread/965ef6fd-f145-4f7f-a3a2-1562c8acb084/) forum). To handle this, you would need to use `catch` clauses in a `try-catch` statement that are specific to this exception type. So, in C# you would do something like:

```
try
{
    // ... Run some code that might cause the error in question ...
}
catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
{
    // ... Run some code that handles the error in question ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of a global exception code in .NET -- and there really could never be, since it implies that *every* author of *every* exception class on the planet would have to collaborate in order to choose codes.

You also cannot assume that a particular message signals an exception of a particular type, since the message can (in the general case) be freely chosen at the throw site.

You *could* do a type switch on `exception.GetType()` to find what the runtime type of an exception is, but that is not guaranteed to be a solution (it depends on what was actually thrown, which could be a vanilla `System.Exception` for all we know).

What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to work with devices which like to broke COM port and then only restart of the machine can help, i need to recognize it and react.